# ajax call is never post back to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make an ajax call back to the server to save the new data into the database:
here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveNewApplication")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        appName: newAppName,
        appDesc: newAppDesc,
        expire: newDaysToExpire,
        displayNote: newDspNote,
        adminRole: newAdminRole,
        defualtRole: newDefaultRole,
        active: newIsActive
    },
    dataType: '',
    success: function () {
        alert("new data has been saved");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error happened whiles saving the new application data");
    }
});
```

I set a break point at the "SaveNewApplication" function but the break point is never hit!
here is the "SaveNewApplication" function:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    public void SaveNewApplication(string appName, string appDesc, int expire, string displayNote, string adminRole,
       string defualtRole, bool active)
    {

    }
```

the success function in the ajax call is never executed

Comment: your contentType is wrong, or your data is being sent in the wrong format. jQuery will not convert your object to json automagically, you'll have to do that yourself if you want to post JSON using `JSON.stringify(thedata)`

Comment: have you checked any errors in firebug ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you're actually sending JSON if you specify your contentType as json. [JSON.stringify() converts javascript values into JSON strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveNewApplication")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        appName: newAppName,
        appDesc: newAppDesc,
        expire: newDaysToExpire,
        displayNote: newDspNote,
        adminRole: newAdminRole,
        defualtRole: newDefaultRole,
        active: newIsActive
    }),
    dataType: '',
    success: function () {
        alert("new data has been saved");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error happened whiles saving the new application data");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem, one of the passed parameters is null, so the call is never made back to the server.